# Float value gets too small

Tags: java, limit, minimum

I am trying to print out the values of an equation that I am working with. The equation is:

```
(2^k)/(k!)
```

I am working with Java and using Floats but I am having a problem that occurs when k gets large. As it gets bigger the bottom of the equation is substantially larger than the top. So as you can imagine the limit of the equation is going to 0. But as the number gets smaller, it goes past `1 * 10^-31` and once it seems to pass that value, the float seems to increase. I assume that the number gets too small and once it passes `10^-31` Java reacts and makes it a larger value. Similar to how if a float value goes past the `Float.MAX_VALUE` it goes to `-Float.MAX_VALUE`. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? It is messing up the results of what I am trying to accomplish.

Thank you.

Comment: how about using `BigInteger` class or `BigDecimal` if you really need to calculate a value that big?

Comment: The thing is it's not a value "that big", its a value "that small". Also I am using Java's Graphics library to draw lines that are the size of the value of the equation. So I need to be able to draw the value as well

Comment: This is an assignment that I need to work with. I am drawing the length of the result of the equation at k. I dont know what you mean by there is no need to compute k. Yes there is, I need it for the equation like it says... I am running k from 1 to n where n is whatever value is specified.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at `(2^k)/(k!)`. For k=1, we have:

```
2/1
```

For k=2, we have

```
2/1 * 2/2
```

For k=3, we have

```
2/1 * 2/2 * 2/3
```

And so on. Notice there's never any need to actually compute the full denominator.

Comment: I was misunderstanding, I thought you were saying that k! could be simplified. So you're saying to simplify the final result.

Comment: I'm saying you can compute the final result any way you want. Don't pick the worst possible way. You can multiply and divide in whatever order or combination you please.

Comment: Right, I just didnt think to look at the results of the equation and simplify it off of that. Thanks!